My MongoDB change stream stops receiving events after my atlas custer restarts with new Primary
My debugging Steps:

Added a cron (every 5 min) job that inserts (key : watchID val : "randomString") a document into the collection which has an watch applied on it.
Then listened for the insert event with the watchID key.
Logged every time the watch was active.

When comparing the last log entry with the MongoDB server Metrics

I found the restarting and the election of the new Primary may be the cause.

Atlas UI showing change of primary and server restart
How to get events after the server has undergone restart or election or both.
Using :

MongoDB Atlas M0 7.0.11
Mongoose 7.3.1
Node v20.3.1


what's your changestream configuration?

@dododo
const Users = mongoose.model("Users", usersSchema);
Users.watch([], { fullDocument: "updateLookup" }).on("change", async (data) => {
//Handling events with switch case.
})

Try checking resumeToken options, in particular StartAfter: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/#startafter-for-change-streams

How does your code handle a changestream invalidation?

@Joe I am not aware of changeStream invalidation please elaborate or attach any docs Thanks.

@ dodo yeah, i have to add resume token but how to check if the change stream has ended or not.

See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/change-events/invalidate/#invalidate

@Joe Thanks for the reply, From docs "Change streams opened on collections raise an invalidate event when a drop, rename, or dropDatabase operation occurs that affects the watched collection.", this is case is not being handled but if this were to happen my whole application would error.
